# Running Vagrant Up Headless on Windows->EC2->Windows

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, vagrant, vagrant-plugin

We are running Vagrant on Windows using the EC2 plugin to spin up a Windows box.

When running our Vagrant file we are getting prompted for our username/password for the SMB share.

How do we edit our Vagrant file or add command line switches to suppress this user interaction?

Our Vagrant command is `vagrant up --provider=aws`

Our Vagrant File is as below

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "dummy"
    config.vm.guest = :windows
    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 3389, host: 3389
    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 22, host: 22
    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 5985, host: 5985, id: "winrm", auto_correct: true
    config.ssh.username = "user"
    config.ssh.password = "password"
    config.ssh.insert_key = false

  config.vm.provider :aws do |aws, override|
    aws.access_key_id = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
    aws.secret_access_key = "KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK"
    aws.ami = "ami-i866gft"
  end
end
```

Comment: can you please look at the answer an decide if that helps you in any way?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have a different way of working with vagrant. This works for my case without any interaction:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
config.vm.box = "dummy.box"
config.vm.synced_folder '.', '/vagrant', disabled: true


config.vm.provider :aws do |aws, override|
  aws.access_key_id = "XXXX"
  aws.secret_access_key = "XXXX"
  aws.ami ="ami-f2f5f9ef"
  aws.security_groups = ['instance-name-on-aws']
  aws.keypair_name = "ssh_key_name"

  override.ssh.username = "user"
  override.ssh.private_key_path = "ssh_key_name.pem"
  aws.instance_type = "t2.micro"
  aws.region = "region"
end
end
```